# Serial port parity check failed in boost asio

Tags: c++, linux, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I use boost asio serial port. When a serial port is open I can set a parity, for example:

```
boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::even
```

Then I start read a serial port:

```
serialPort_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(serialPortData_),
boost::bind(&MySerialPort::readComplete, this,
boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

What happens when parity check is failed? Is readComplete called with specific error (which?) and bytes_transferred = 0?

Answer (score 2):

Boost just wraps the system error in an `error_code` instance.

So it's whatever error code the underlying syscalls (like `::tcsendbreak`) return.

Upon error, most async operations leave `bytes_transferred` unspecified (unless, obviously specified otherwise).